# Import a token to MyEtherWallet? How do I determine `Decimal` value?

Tags: tokens, myetherwallet

I'm new to MEW, but wanted to understand how to determine the `Decimal` value when adding a custom token.

I pulled [the `contract address` from etherscan](https://etherscan.io/token/TokenCard): 0xaaaf91d9b90df800df4f55c205fd6989c977e73a

The `token symbol` is: TKN

I'm unsure how to determine `Decimal`.

Where do I pull this information from?

Comment: I guess the publisher of the coin should make decimal places public.

Comment: Sorry, but what does that mean?  The decimal is defined somewhere?  Can you explain background on this?

Comment: When you create a standard token based on Ethereum [link](https://www.ethereum.org/token), you define the decimal places used by the coin. You need this because there are no decimal places in the blockchain. So, if the publisher of token specifies decimal places to be 2, it means 100 tokens is actually 1.00 tokens.

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation.  Is it safe to assume that all tokens are open source?  If so, where can one find the source?

Comment: `TKN` was listed already on MEW.  Apologies.  Good info to know regardless.  I was able to get the answer of `8` decimal places on the `TKN` slack channel.

Comment: Great. Glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you will find in the [ERC20](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard) information describing the token contarct:

```
uint8 public decimals;
```

it describes how many decimals to show to the user. for example

for a `decimals = 3`, the user needs to have a 1000 TKN to see 1.00 in Mist or Ethereum Wallet, if you have only 1TKN you will see 0.001.

if we use `decimals=16` this is mean that 100 tokens for every 1 ETH.

[Most common value](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/Ethereum_Based_Tokens) for decimal parameter is 18, in this case the token is like a wei  (`ether=10^18 wei`)

Comment: note the TKN decimal is 8.  How do I determine this for a specific token? As in... I researched and found it for TKN, but is token code open source or something ? Is there some open repo I can review that contains this information?

Comment: look at the link i shared before https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/Ethereum_Based_Tokens you will find a plenty of contracts which are tokens contract and well commented

Comment: Thanks.  So, I do assume that it's "accepted standard" to release the code for your token?

Comment: ERC20 is a standard to follow to setup your token contract i advise you to look at : https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard  https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens  https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20

Comment: I meant a cultural standard for authors to share their source.

Comment: are you asking about releasing or not your code?

Comment: I'm asking if it's common practice that token code is open and reviewable.

Comment: yes, it is a common practice, this transparency establishes the trust between the token issuer and the users.

Comment: Thank you.  Generally, would I see code published to github?